# I need to create a custom page on NSIS where the contents of a .md file are displayed in a textbox or listbox

Tags: installation, nsis, nsdialogs

I have been trying to use NSIS to create an installer for an application. I tried to add my "changelog.md" 's contents to it and so I created a custom page.

I'm a bit new on this and I can't seem to have the .md file's contents to display properly with the right formatting and linebreaks.

All I need to do is to fill up the text control I created with the whole text.

```
;--------------------------------
;Pages

Function ReadMarkdownFile
  ; Open the file for reading
  FileOpen $R0 "path\Changelog.md" r
  ${If} $R0 == ""
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP "Failed to open the file!"
    Abort
  ${EndIf}

  ; Initialize the variable to store the file contents
  StrCpy $0 ""

  ; Read the file contents line by line
  loop:
    FileRead $R0 $R1
    ${If} $R1 == "" ; Reached the end of the file
      Goto done
    ${EndIf}
    StrCpy $0 "$0$R1$\r$\n" ; Append the line to the variable with line breaks
    Goto loop

  done:
  FileClose $R0
FunctionEnd


Function myPageCreate
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "App" "LastUpdate"

  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $0
  ${If} $0 == error
      Abort
  ${EndIf}

  ; Call the function to read the Markdown file
  Call ReadMarkdownFile

  ${NSD_CreateRichEdit} 0 13u 100% -13u ;this is likely the problem
  Pop $0

  ; Set the contents of the RichEdit control
  ${NSD_SetText} $0 $0

  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
Page custom myPageCreate 


  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  ;!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $StartMenuFolder
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  
;--------------------------------
```

I have tried multiple solutions (editing a LICENSE page, ${NSD_CreateRichEdit}, ${NSD_CreateText}, among others) but the farthest I've gotten to was getting the text from said file on a single line.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

First off, neither NSIS nor Windows has native markdown support. If you want fancy formatting then you need to use a [.rtf file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) instead.

Your code has many bugs, you cannot put the RichEdit handle and the text in the same variable! (`${NSD_SetText} $0 $0` is never correct).

The easy way to display text on a page is to just use a license page (you can have as many pages as you want):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

PageEx license
    Caption ": Readme"
    LicenseText "Please read me"
    LicenseData "${__FILE__}"
 PageExEnd

PageEx license
    LicenseData "${NSISDIR}\Copying"
PageExEnd

Page Custom myPageCreate
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Function myPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateRichEdit} 0 13u 100% -13u ""
Pop $1
FileOpen $0 "${NSISDIR}\Copying" r ; A real installer would copy this file to $pluginsdir and read it from there
StrCmp $0 "" done
ClearErrors
loop:
    FileRead $0 $2 ; Read one line
    IfErrors done
    SendMessage $1 ${EM_SETSEL} "" -1
    SendMessage $1 ${EM_SETSEL} -1 ""
    SendMessage $1 ${EM_REPLACESEL} "" "STR:$2" ; Append the line
    Goto loop
done:
FileClose $0

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```